# What is a type signature?

Tags: category-theory

> A Category is a context for the study of a particular clsas of mathematical objects. Importantly, a category is not simply a type signature, it has both "nouns" and "verbs", containg specified collections of objects and transformations, called morphisms, between them. page-xi , Category theory in context

What does type signature mean here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature?wprov=sfla1

Comment: The author probably means signature in the sense the term is used in universal algebra. However, the text doesn't really make sense if the author is talking about category theory in the usual sense in mathematics. Can you give a reference to the text you are quoting.

Comment: Category theory in context is named of book if I am not mistaken @RobArthan

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I had a look at the author's online PDF and I think he is quoting the paper referenced as  [Mazur08] (also available online). What Mazur says make sense to me, but Mazur doesn't talk about type signatures. I think the text that is troubling you is just hand-waving and I'd recommend you just move on.